# OOM error on training, but not on validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

A have a deep convolution network with approximate 120 layers. I attempt to train on `[7,368,368,1]` batches successfully. Also, I can easily give `[1,2700,2700,1]` as an input on validation step. But I can not increase batch size from 7 to higher (for example 20), tensorflow fails with

```
 OOM when allocating tensor with shape[20,10,368,368].
```

How is it possible, when on validation we have `[1,10,2700,2700]` tensor?

Comment: Do you training on GPU or CPU? How much RAM do you have? How many parametrs?

Comment: GPU, geforce gtx 1080 ti, Trainable params: 268258, RAM 30GB

Comment: Can you share with me your model?

Answer (score 0):

You do only forward pass on validation dataset. But you do forward and backward passes on training. Backward pass probably uses more resources.

Answer (score 0):

On *validation* we just have forward pass so the data just flows forward and there is no need to keep output of previous layers. But in *training* you need to keep some layers output and use them in backward pass (on the other hand I think tensorflow keeps parameters gradient in each iteration to pass them to optimizer). As the result, the *training* will use much more RAM